# Checking friendship existence using the Twitter API

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I want to write an application with JavaScript and the [twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friendships/exists)  for checking if two twitter usernames are friends. If A is following B, the opposite or if no one follows each other.

The user types the two usernames in a form.

So i will be using `https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/exists.json?screen_name_a=a&screen_name_b=b`

And this is how I will grab my two twitter names in the script, right?

```
var a = document.getElementById("username_a").value;
var b = document.getElementById("username_b").value;
```

But how do I put correctly the two usernames the user filled in the API twitter line, I mean with $a and $b? And how can I enable them with a button event click?

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
$twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/exists.json?screen_name_a='.$id1.'&screen_name_b=' .$id2);

$id1 = " ";

$id2 = " ";

var a = document.getElementById("$id1").value;
var b = document.getElementById("$id2").value;
```

You can try, I'm not sure.

Comment: Uhm... Is this a mixture of PHP and Javascript?